# Why do my standard CSS Triangles have their points cut off?

Tags: html, css

So I have the following two triangles:

[image: two triangles]

The points are cut off, but my code is literally just this:

```
.navCaret {
position: relative;
float: right;
right: 5px;
top: 5px;
width: 0; 
height: 0;
border-top: 9px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
border-left: 9px solid #ccc;
}

.navCaretOL {
position: relative;
float: right;
right: 9px;
top: 9px;
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 9px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
border-left: 9px solid #333;
}
```

And as you can see [in this JSFiddle,](https://jsfiddle.net/6f4yxp4e/) it actually DOESN'T cut the edges off when rendering these triangles in a JSFiddle.

All in all this could not be a more standard way of creating a pure CSS triangle and has worked for me many, many times. Anyone have any idea what could be causing this strange behavior? Thanks.

EDIT: By the way, confirmed to behave the same way in IE and Chrome, both latest versions.

Comment: it looks like your parent container that holds the arrows is smaller than the arrow itself

Comment: Huh...interesting. The container in the actual page I'm working in is 48px high and 100% width (this will be for a callout bubble that appears horizontally in a navbar), so this should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle is only pointy when the border stretches all the way to the center, meaning anything altering the content box has to be `0` - this includes `width/height` and `padding`. Check for other css rules that overwrite your `height: 0;` or add some padding.

```css
.navCaret {
  border-top: 9px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
  border-left: 9px solid #ccc;
  outline: 1px solid red; /*for illustration purposes only*/
}

.navCaretOL {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 9px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
  border-left: 9px solid #333;
  white-space: nowrap;    /*for illustration purposes only*/
  outline: 1px solid red; /*for illustration purposes only*/
}
```

```html
<div class="navCaret">height != 0</div>
<br>
<div class="navCaretOL">height == 0 (content is overflowing)</div>
```

Comment: You are definitely right about this...but after deleting every height property in the page except for the ones on these elements (there were only a few others), and also removing my bootstrap hosting link in case it was something in the theme, the triangles still look the same. I also tried to use div.navCaret and div.navCaretOL to increase specificity, but that had no effect.

Comment: Check the "computed" tab in the developer console -> styles/element section. It tells you, what the actually rendered height of the element is (and where the according rule originates from).

Comment: Weird...Firefox console doesn't even have it in the list, IE console says 0, and Chrome console says...um...22px?????? But then when I expand the one in Chrome, it takes me to the .navCaretOL class declaration and highlights "height: 0" within it.

Comment: Good to see your problem could be solved. If you liked my question you can give a +1. Also, accept your or my answer by clicking the check mark - this indicates to other SO users, that your problem has been solved.

Comment: Yes I know, but I have so little rep that stack doesn't let me upvote posts. I want to upvote your answer and accept mine (because while yours helped me get there a lot, mine will show other users what the actual problem/solution was), but I can't even accept my own answer "until tomorrow." I love that there are helpful people like yourself on this site, but there seem to be a lot of very, very dumb auto-moderating rules.

Comment: That's no problem at all. Just accept your answer and give me an upvote later;-) I think you get the privilege once you have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

OMG I just figured this out by going through my page and deleting each CSS rule line-by-line. Apparently the problem was caused by the following rule:

```
div.navUpper * {
    padding-top: 4px;
}
```

'.navUpper' is the container my carets were in. The '*' selector was applying 4px padding to them -- the effects of which can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/6f4yxp4e/8/

Thanks again to those who responded -- you were both right in different ways.